# Object class rotating wrongly when it's called in movieclip class (My Arcade Game)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, actionscript, flash-cs5

i have Cannon's class and it can rotate towards player !!

```
package com.musuh  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import com.ply.Heli;

public class Cannon extends MovieClip {
    public var enTarget:Heli;

    public function Cannon(enTarget:Heli) {
        this.enTarget = enTarget;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , update);
    }

    public function fire (m:MouseEvent){
        trace("fire");
    } 

    function update (e:Event) {
        if (parent != null) {
        var dx = enTarget.x - x ;
        var dy = enTarget.y - y ;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx)/Math.PI*180-90;
        rotation = angle;
        }
    }
}
```

}

when i called it to main class , it works fine (it can rotating towards player ) !!! , but when i called it inside Boss class (because in my game this boss can have at least 3 cannon ),it wasn't error but rotate wrongly towards player .. Why is it like that ?

it's the Boss Class

```
package com.musuh  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import com.peluru.bossBullet;
import com.ply.Heli;
import com.musuh.Cannon;

public class Boss extends MovieClip {
    private var speedX:int = 6;
    private var dx:Number; // speed and direction
    public var bossHP:Number=20;
    private var gun:Cannon;
    public var hits:Array;
    public var target:Heli;

    public function Boss(target:Heli) {
    this.target = target;
    bossBullets = new Array();
    hits = new Array(hit1,hit2,hit3,hit4,hit5,hit6);
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE , onAddedToStage);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlane)
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update)
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void 
    {
        gun = new Cannon(target);
        gun.x = 0;
        gun.y = 200;
        // add cannon to the MC Pitboss
        addChild(gun);
    }

    public function movePlane(e:Event){
        // move plane
        this.x +=speedX;  
        {
            speedX *= -1;
        }
        if (this.x <= 20)
        {
            speedX *= -1;
        }
    }   
}   
}
```

and it's the **SCREEN SHOOT**

http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9250/1p0a.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object rotate wrongly when called inside Boss class !!! AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878018/object-rotate-wrongly-when-called-inside-boss-class-as3). You should edit your original question, not post the same one with new details.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the code where you actually add the Boss object? it looks like your

```
Boss.scaleX = -1
```

that'd explain the flipped x axis

But without seeing the code where you add your boss to main, I can't be sure.